# How to access Subversion from Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, svn, plsql

For a governmental agency, we build a release management system developped in PHP and Oracle. The data for this application is stored in database tables and is processed with PL/SQL packages and procedures.

The release management process is extensively based on metadata coming from Subversion repositories.  We access the repositories from PL/SQL through the internal Oracle JVM to execute svn commands on the unix server on which resides the Oracle instances.  The results from svn commands are received in XML and parsed before beeing processed by PL/SQL.  Accessing Subversion this way is not very performant for frequent repeated use.

Currently, what we do is storing the Subversion metadata in database tables at each commit in the Subversion repositories (via Subversion hooks).  We extract the log information for each Subversion transaction and keep it in some oracle tables. We are then able to obtain Subversion metadata with normal SQL queries.

Is there better ways to access Subversion from PL/SQL ?

Comment: At my previous employer, we did it exactly that way. (That is, we inserted the subversion metadata into oracle using a hook.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Oracle's Java JVM, you could try to use [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) to communicate with the SVN server nativly from Java, instead of shelling out to the operating system to execute commands.

Comment: Currently, java is only a passthrough between the unix shell and PL/SQL.  With SVNKit, I would have to reproduce in java what the svn commands are doing to give me the results and define a new data structure before passing it back to PL/SQL. Not sure of the gain.

Comment: I could also define interfaces between PL/SQL and SVNKit but I'm not sure if the multiple context changes required for obtaining a single revision log would be more performant than parsing a single XML.  I could give it a try.

Comment: It just depends on whatever works best for you.  I almost always try to find a native solution, and then fall back to running command line things if the native solution proves unworkable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic flow makes sense.  I would recommend doing experiments to see where exactly the performance bottlenecks are and then take if from there.   For example, is it crossing from PL/SQL to Oracle JVM?   Is it JVM shelling out to execute the svn command?  Is it the svn round trip?   Is it the parsing of the XML?

Let's say, for example, it's the svn round trip.  Maybe you could have a process on the oracle machine that caches answers from the svn server so that at times the round trip could be avoided?    Maybe the svn round trip could be async?

But, like I said, you need to know where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for an API to integerate Subversion and Oracle. I need to be able to pull Oracle PL/SQL objects (procedures, packages) into Subversion and then once changes are made to objects it should be applied to those objects in Oracle database.

Comment: To pull the PL/SQL objects, query the all_source view. To push them back in, consider a post-commit hook in subversion. Careful mapping will have to be done so that you can tell which schema a given file should be compiled into.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is to use software which stays between ORACLE and SVN and synchronizes PL/SQL with sources.

Here is one of these programs which can be started by cron:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbcode-svn-sync/
.